# Regex verificar IP

Tags: c#, regex, ip, devexpress

Estou implementando uma regex para aceitar endereço IP, para isso estou utilizando uma mask no componente textEdit do DevExpress, porem quando deixo o campo em branco ou com apenas uma parte preenchida trava todos os outros controles do form.

Regex utilizada:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

Comment: `([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` -- proteger o `.`

Comment: VictorFreitas, o que são caracteres vazios? E queres caracteres vazios no IP?

Comment: Desculpa Joao, o certo seria aceitar o campo vazio, no caso do usuário desistir de preencher o campo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solução

`/^((1?\d{1,2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}(1?\d{1,2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$|^$/`

#### Explicação

- Note que você quer validar IP então não se pode usar simplesmente `\d{1,3}`, pois você estaria aceitando `999`.
- `(1?\d{1,2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))` esta REGEX vai validar números de 0 a 255.
- `((1?\d{1,2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.){3}` adendo do ponto literal e deve se repetir 3 vezes
- o `^$` seria o "nada", no caso inicia e já termina.

Seja funcionando no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/DKGQrc/1).

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é usar um método próprio, como este para validar IP no formado IPv4:

```
public bool ValidateIPv4(string ipString)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipString))
    {
        return false;
    }

    string[] splitValues = ipString.Split('.');

    if (splitValues.Length != 4)
    {
        return false;
    }

    byte tempForParsing;

    return splitValues.All(r => byte.TryParse(r, out tempForParsing));
}
```

Implementação:

```
string ip1 = "q.1;00.1.";       
string ip2 = "127.0.0.1";
string ip3 = "999.0.0.2";

Console.WriteLine(ValidateIPv4(ip1));
Console.WriteLine(ValidateIPv4(ip2));
Console.WriteLine(ValidateIPv4(ip3));
```

Saída:

> False
>   True
>   False

Este método é uma alternativa ao [IPAdress.Tryparse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse.aspx) que possui limitações e pode retornar resultados incorretos. Ele também e de fácil manutenção já que ele possui apenas três regras para determinar se o endereço IP é válido.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11412991/5429980).

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar essa regex:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

A princípio ela vai validar cada linha da sua TextEdit, começando da primeira letra, caso queira validar em qualquer parte do texto, remova o ^ do início.

Comment: Essa sua regex está com alguns problemas, além de não aceitar o campo vazio, ela fica mostrando o caracteres de ^ no inicio da string e o caractere de $ no final da string.